# How to include object in regular expression

Tags: regex, r, object

```
namez <- c("foo2003", "bar2340", "naught45")
patternz <- "03"
grepl("[patternz]$",namez)
```

It does not work. What should I substitute [patternz] with, so the regular expression will match the contents of the patternz variable?

*[edit]* Notice that I want to match the string "03", not the digits "0" and "3" separately.

Comment: @shhhhimhuntingrabbits, readability trumps small gains in performance. That is why I selected your solution. But I'll select Gavin's one because, besides using the standard library, it creates the regular expression within the variable rather than around it. That is very simple and elegant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Must admit to struggling to see what the problem is here. For the example stated nothing more than

```
R> namez <- c("foo2003", "bar2340", "naught45")
R> patternz <- "03"
R> grepl(patternz, namez)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

is required as `patternz` *is* a character vector and the aim is not to match `0` **&** `3` but to match the literal `"03"`

If you need this to match only at the end of the strings, then we do need to add `"$"` either by hand:

```
R> patternz2 <- "03$"
R> grepl(patternz2, namez)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

or via a `paste0()` operation

```
R> grepl(paste0(patternz, "$"), namez)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

The issue is to use `patternz` as the actual regexp and base R functions handle this perfectly.

Comment: I know, but SO isn't a static site and no-one seemed bothered to update their answers to match the developing discussion.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I thought sleeping through the night was allowed? I'm in Australia! There, post edited. :)

Comment: @DanielMachado Sleeping? That's frowned upon here. To be clear, you should accept whichever Answer you want to and which suits you best. The other Answers are here for other people with similar problems. If you were happy with the original accept, stick with that. The voting and the accept are two different things.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you need to create a character vector for `grepl()`, using `paste0()` seems to work, though is not that elegant:

```
> grepl(paste0("[", patternz, "]$"), namez)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Wait a minute. Why put in the "[" / "]"?

Comment: @DWin - I apparently misinterpreted the OP's question as signifying that his character string "03" should be matched as a character class. I guess he was using `[]` to try and tell R that is should look for an object named `patternz`instead.

Answer (score 4):

package `gsubfn` is your friend

```
library(gsubfn)
namez <- c("foo2003", "bar2340", "naught45")
patternz <- "03"
fn$grepl("[$patternz]$",namez)

#> fn$grepl("[$patternz]$",namez)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Originally you indicated you wanted to match a 0 or a 3 at the end of the string. In your comment you allude to maybe wanting to match '03' in which case

```
fn$grepl("$patternz$",namez)
```

would be more appropriate.

also

```
fn$grepl("`patternz`$",namez)
```

in this case might be more appropriate as the `$` has  double meanings.

Comment: Nice one @ttmaccer, but the result I was expecting was TRUE FALSE FALSE. Any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: The 'gsubfn' package is very kewl, but it's overkill here.

Comment: I guess it's appropriate when the questioner is happy and on that basis I suppose it qualifies.